# Linking keywords from python to a csv that stores the solutions to the issue the user is experiencing

Tags: python, csv, input

I have a code that allows me to identify keywords inputted from a user and the system displays the problem the keyword linked to and asks if it is correct. If the user inputs yes a solution is given

```
# The following is a database of problems, keywords, and solutions.

PROBLEMS = (('My phone does not turn on.',
             {'power', 'turn', 'on', 'off'},
             ('put it on charger.',))



# These are possible answers accepted for yes/no style questions.
POSITIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('yes', 'true', 'correct')))
NEGATIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('no', 'false', 'incorrect')))


def main():
    """Find out what problem is being experienced and provide a solution."""
    description = input('Welcome to the repair centre. Please state the problem with your device: ')
    words = {''.join(filter(str.isalpha, word))
             for word in description.lower().split()}
    for problem, keywords, steps in PROBLEMS:
        if words & keywords:
            print('This may be what you are experiencing:')
            print(problem)
            if get_response('Does this match your problem? '):
                print('Please follow the solution given')
                for number, step in enumerate(steps, 1):
                    print('{}. {}'.format(number, step))
                print('Once you have carried out the solution suggested by the system the problem with your device should be fixed .')
                print('If you have carried out the solution suggested by the system and the problem is not fixed, please take the device  to either the manufacturer or to the repair shop to get it fixed professionally.')
                break
    else:
        print('Unfortunately the repair centre cannot help you with your problem.')


def get_response(query):
    """Ask the user yes/no style questions and return the results."""
    while True:
        answer = input(query).casefold()
        if answer:
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in POSITIVE):
                return True
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in NEGATIVE):
                return False
        print('Please respond with the positive or negative answer listed : yes, true, correct, no, false, incorrect.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However how can i store all the solutions in a text file and make the keywords stored in python link to it depending on the user input.
I want a specific line from the text file to be outputted to the user. 
Help will be appreciated

Comment: is `casefold` really necessary when you specify the strings?

Comment: yes i must link the keywords to a csv file @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: ... yes but you realize `casefold` is doing nothing to your strings?

Comment: I would probably store it as a csv (using the `csv` module), and then load it into a python dictionary when you start up your program

Comment: is there any way possible you can show me the code for that @PatrickHaugh

Comment: if i don't add casefold an error comes up @juanpa.arrivillaga TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: @sufiyaaltaf that doesn't make any sense...

Comment: A side note: `map` has been supplanted by much more readable generator expressions.

Comment: i tried @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: what is a much more readable generator than map??? @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: `POSITIVE = tuple(s.casefold() for s in ('yes', 'true', 'correct'))`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev eh, a lot of `map`s use-cases have been supplanted by generator expressions, but I think the readability benefits are different on a case-by-case basis. Indeed, in this case, it is more readable to use `map`. It is also likely faster. `map` is still the fastest way to map a built-in function onto an iterable. Of course, these speed differences would not be large.

Comment: About the question: you either fully load the text file into some data structure in memory and return strings from there, or generate some helper data structure that would tell you at which offset you need to read in each case. There are too many possible solutions to give an example and your code isn't even any relevant to the task you're asking about to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

We're going to store the keywords and solutions in a `csv` file. The first entry on each line will be the solution, and all the others will be keywords that direct to this solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

sol_dict = defaultdict(set)
with open('solutions.csv', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, quotechar='|')
    for solution, *keywords in r:
        for keyword in keywords:
            sol_dict['keyword'].add(solution)
```

So now we have this dictionary, `sol_dict`.  We can query a keyword `sol_dict['power']` and you get back a set of strings, each a solution.  (When you make the csv, if you want commas in the solution, you can wrap it in the `quotechar`, `|`).

Then walking through the solutions would look something like

```
problem = input('What is your problem?')
for solution in set.union(*(sol_dict[word] for word in problem.split())):
    # Whatever you want to do with solutions
    print(solution)
```

Comment: i followed all your instructions however when i run the code it says invalid syntax

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'union' requires a 'set' object but received a 'generator'

Comment: Change it to `for solution in set.union(*(sol_dict[word] for word in problem.split())):`